# How to insert data in to temp table from two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables with same columns with diffrent name Request and Archive_Request. these table contains the lot of records. I want to insert value in temp table #TEMPTABLE  from both the tables without any efficient performance

```
This is temp table #TEMPTABLE (RequestId, RequestType, RequestStatus)
```

Below is the query to select the data from the tables.

```
SELECT RequestID, RequestType, RequestStatus
       FROM Request 
       WHERE ((UPPER(SOURCE) IN ('KMP', 'DOCUSIGN') 
       AND UPPER(RequestStatus)  IN ('RETURNED REQUEST', 'COMPLETED')))   
       AND (CreatedBy = @MyID);


SELECT RequestID, RequestType, RequestStatus
       FROM Archive_Request 
       WHERE ((UPPER(SOURCE) IN ('KMP', 'DOCUSIGN') 
       AND UPPER(RequestStatus)  IN ('COMPLETED')))   
       AND (CreatedBy = @MyID);
```

I have tried this query to insert the data in temp table but it is not working. can you please give me solution

```
INSERT INTO #TEMPTABLE (RequestId, RequestType, RequestStatus)

    SELECT B.RequestId, C.RequestId, B.RequestType, C.RequestType, B.RequestStatus, C.RequestStatus
    FROM Request AS B , Archive_Request AS C
    WHERE ((UPPER(B.SOURCE) IN ('KMP', 'DOCUSIGN') and ((UPPER(C.SOURCE) IN ('KMP', 'DOCUSIGN') 
    AND UPPER(B.RequestStatus)  IN ('RETURNED REQUEST', 'COMPLETED'))) 
    AND UPPER(C.RequestStatus)  IN ('COMPLETED')))
    AND (B.CreatedBy = @MyID) AND (C.CreatedBy = @MyID) ;
```

Comment: When you encounter an error, then post the complete error message. You surely encountered one with your attempt. A join is not what you need here - especially one using the [old-style join syntax](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) which you should avoid.

Comment: Why are you using `UPPER` on your columns in the `WHERE`? If you're using a case sensitive collation then `'KMP'` should *not* match `'kmp'`. If you aren't, they do nothing but harm the performance of the query.

Answer (score 0):

How about `union all`?

```
SELECT RequestID, RequestType, RequestStatus
INTO #TEMPTABLE
   FROM Request 
   WHERE ((UPPER(SOURCE) IN ('KMP', 'DOCUSIGN') 
   AND UPPER(RequestStatus)  IN ('RETURNED REQUEST', 'COMPLETED')))   
   AND (CreatedBy = @MyID);
UNION ALL
SELECT RequestID, RequestType, RequestStatus
   FROM Archive_Request 
   WHERE ((UPPER(SOURCE) IN ('KMP', 'DOCUSIGN') 
   AND UPPER(RequestStatus)  IN ('COMPLETED')))   
   AND (CreatedBy = @MyID);
```

Comment: I have 1lakh records in the table, is this will not create any performance issue?

Comment: The "performance issue" here is the lack of SARGability in your original query, not the `UNION ALL` @chub. Also, what is a "lakh"?

Comment: 1 million records @gordon

Comment: @chub . . . No more so than your original two queries.  `union all` adds little overhead.